# Changing Visual Studio 2015 UserName

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, tfs-2015

I am connecting to My team Project in TFS 2015 using Administrator in Visual Studio every time I log in.

[image]

But I have some other accounts in my AD using which I want to connect to TFS-2015 and I am able to connect to TFS-2015 using TFS Web portal.

[image]

How would I connect my Visual Studio from the user account as "Muhammad.awais" in my case.

I tried following thing too but it did not work.What is the correct way of connecting Visual Studio to the TFS Team Project?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logging in the machine with your domain account, TFS will cached the ID info and will automatic connect with your account.

You should create/use a **local accoun**t on the  machine to **login in windows**, then login in VS with your new account.